# Does an off-the-shelf router have all LAN ports bridged?

Tags: networking, router, routing, dhcp

I want to roll my own router, as the one provided by my ISP is terrible.

The router of course provides DHCP and routing on all 4 of the LAN ports.

Does this mean that it provides DHCP and routing on each port individually? Or does it mean that it bridges all four ports in software and then provides DHCP and routing to that bridge device?

To the user, it would look functionally identical. But when setting up the router, there is a difference. I'm assuming one is more "correct" than the other. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the 4 LAN ports are bridged on most routers. On most routers, it's actually a hardware ethernet switch that bridges them. Though the switch chip often supports VLAN tags, so you can address ports individually (but usually not with the firmware provided by the manufacturer).

But details can vary from router to router. It depends on the brand and model.

> But when setting up the router, there is a difference.

You usually won't be able to set this up.

> I'm assuming one is more "correct" than the other.

Why should one be more "correct" than the other? But assuming all 4 LAN ports belong to a single broadcast domain, bridging is more natural (and keeps load off the CPU if supported by hardware).

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a consumer "*router*" actually looks more like this:

[image: home router internals]

The Modem may be an external box connected via Ethernet, but is often built-in.

- All red links are "*internet*" traffic
- All blue links are "*internal*" traffic, and allow internal devices to communicate with one another.

A single DHCP server is used, that assignes addresses to all internal devices - WiFi clients included.

In some cases, you might find that it's possible to isolate WiFi clients from the wired network, and even from each other. It's also possible that this scenario can run side-by-side with your own home network - for example BT make use of *all* of their consumer equipment to offer their [BT WiFi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BT_Wi-fi) services across the country - pubs, restaraunts and even residential properties provide a connection that their users can make use of that is logically isolated from the customer's wired and wireless network.

---

> Does this mean that it provides DHCP and routing on each port individually?

No, internal ports will share a single router (often implemented in software, e.g: Linux's [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables)).

> What is the best practice?

That really depends what you're after... if you want to isolate some ports from others (for example a "*home office*" vs "*family*"), then you'll want to look into having multiple "*internal*" networks, with routing and fireware configuration set up for each independantly.

If you're a home user, then the chances are that you just want a single internal network.

> I want to roll my own router

... there are plenty of suitable off-the-shelf products that allow you to stop using the ISP's router.

If you want a more hands-on approach, then you could look into using a Linux machine running something like [pfSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PfSense), or you could use off-the-shelf hardware that is supported by the popular [OpenWRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt) project.

Fundamentally though, I'd recommend *against* rolling your own router, unless you're really comfortable with being hands-on and responsible with this sort of workload and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If all ports are to belong to the same subnet, then they *have* to be bridged. Using individual interfaces wouldn't really work.

When hosts contact another device on the same IP subnet, they don't use the router at all. Instead they broadcast an ARP query to learn the target device's MAC address and talk directly to that address. This wouldn't work if the two were on separate router interfaces (separate broadcast domains) – the ARP queries wouldn't be forwarded, and if they were, the hosts still couldn't talk to the MAC addresses they learned.

(The meaning of bridging ports is *literally* to merge broadcast domains and allow communications at MAC layer.)

So then the router, sitting in the middle, would have to send "spoofed" ARP replies on behalf on devices which are on the other side, but with its own MAC address every time. (If this was being done, you would easily see it in your computer's ARP cache. This is called proxy-ARP and is occasionally done on public networks.) Now you have the router receiving all packets meant for the recipient, but how does it know which port to forward them through?

Ethernet bridging automatically learns which MAC addresses are behind each port. IP routing, however, does not. If you configure four separate interfaces with the same subnet prefix, you only get four identical routes for the same whole network and the router has no idea which one is correct.

In theory it would be doable – the router now just needs to probe all ports to know which one has the device behind it, e.g. by sending its own ARP queries to all ports and waiting for a response. (Actually it needs to perform this probe *before* sending the spoofed ARP response to the original host – if it turns out that both hosts are behind the same port, then it could confuse them even more.)

But in practice this isn't done and most routers don't even implement any such dynamic proxy-ARP. (There is a 'parprouted' daemon for Linux, but that's about it.)

(The only other exception I've seen for this is fe80::/64 handling in Windows, which probes all interfaces using NDP. It does not have to implement proxying though, as this prefix is non-routeable anyway.)